# How do I turn off javascript support on a project in eclipse?

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

So, here's the problem.

I use eclipse for a PHP project, in which we use smarty templates to format html. One day I was making a small javascript and tried the usual ctrl-space for code completion. I got the popup asking me if I wanted to add javascript support to the project and I thought "well I can at least try it and see how it works". This turned out to be a really bad idea, since editing html/smarty templates is now *extremely* slow.

When I check the project settings I have a Javascript section where I've tried most things but I it seems I can't disable it all together.

So, any ideas of how I can disable javascript support after I've mistakenly activated it?

Answer (score 14):

My project is setup as Java under Eclipse Galileo.  I managed to remove support from it by going to the .project file and deleting the JavaScript Nature (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature).

Comment: Had Kepler hanging on start-up, and this change in .project solved my problem also. Additionally I removed the JS validation in <buildSpec>.

Comment: Using Nodeclipse would hang and I would often have to force-quit Eclipse (Kepler).  This solved the problem!

Comment: Another way is to remove the project facets:
right click on the project -> Properties -> Project Facetes -> right click on javascript -> unlock -> then de-select it!

Answer (score 4):

One problem I've experienced lately is the JavaScript Validation builder fails with a NullPointerException (on Helios).  If you right-click your project, select 'Properties', then 'Builders' and un-check JavaScript Validation it turns off those errors which continued to pop-up on me.

As for JavaScript support itself, check for other 'Builders' in the same area and un-check as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse click: `window->preferences->Javascript->Validator->Errors/Warnings` and uncheck "**Enable JavaScript semantic validation**"

Answer (score -1):

In my case I also had to remove these files from project dir (in addition to removing org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature from .project file) to disable JavaScript support:
.settings/.jsdtscope
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name